# Sorting table regular expressions

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I have this table:

```
id | text
1 111/Aa
2 111/Sa
3 111/1
4 111/2
5 1111/3
6 1111/bbbbbbbb
```

How to sort the table to return the records in the order (the first records of the letters from a to z when / then ascending numbers):

```
111/Aa
1111/bbbbbbbb
111/Sa
111/1
111/2
1111/3
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY IF(text RLIKE '[a-z] ', 1, 2 ) , text ASC;
```

but I got something :/

```
111/1
111/2
111/3
111/AB
111/bbbbbbbb
111/Sa
```

someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The use of PHP and `RLIKE` suggest MySQL.  You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

```
order by (case when substring_index(text, '/', -1) rlike '^[0-9]+') 
               then substring_index(text, '/', -1)
          end) asc,
         substring_index(text, '/', -1) + 0,
         text
```

The first puts the non-numbers (in the last "field') first, in order.  The second orders by the numeric values.  And the final sort is when the last "field" has the same values.

Your example does not work because none of the values contain an letter followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for this solution :]

but there is still a small problem:]

query looks like this:

$query = "SELECT * FROM text order by 
CASE when (substring_index(text, '/', -1) rlike '^[0-9]+') THEN substring_index(text, '/', -1) END ASC,
substring_index(text, '/', -1) + 0,text ASC
";

and returns it:

111/0/A

111/ab

111/st

111/cdfg

111/1

111/1-KS

111/2

111/5

111/67

why "111/0 / A" as the first? ...as rule number after / is fulfilled... and not the sort that way:

111/ab

111/st

111/cdfg

111/0/A

111/1

111/1-KS

111/2

111/5

111/67

and what to do to make it happen ?:D